# Weird theming issue with multiple assemblies

Tags: c#, mahapps.metro, revit-api, theming

I am running into a weird issue with MahApps Themes when different assemblies create windows in succession.

The assemblies are .DLL Add-ins for Autodesk Revit.
Since I am the one creating both, I have also made sure they reference the same versions of MahApps (2.4.9) and ControlzEx (4.4.0).

When launched, both add-ins create a MetroWindow with the given theme and the execution ends when that window is closed. This works well when any add-in first launches.

However, if launching a different add-in after the first has been closed, some controls are displayed with missing visuals, or wrong background colors. It seems like something is getting skipped or missing in their resources?

[Window working normally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zynmB.png)

[Messed up window after other add-in is launched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox5Hd.png)

I attached a debugger to the main process, and I can see each add-in loading their referenced DLLs from their own folder (assemblies are strong named afaik) with the right version.

I have been trying to solve this issues for the past few days and I have run out of ideas.

I have tried both referencing the MahApps theme in the XAML Window.Resources, and also applying a theme via code-behind after the InitializeComponent(), but the result is always the same.

```
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="Odeh.CSI2Revit.Reactions.ImportReactionsWnd"
    ...other ns...
    xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    xmlns:icons="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
    Title="Window Title" Activated="Window_Activated" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Loaded="MetroWindow_Loaded" >
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <!-- Theme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Light.Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary>
                .... more styles
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```